# How to use + or - operators as parameters in Doctrine prepared SQL statement?

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine, prepared-statement

Trying to use the code below:

```
$operator = '+';
$conn = $entityManager->getConnection();
$stmt = $conn->prepare("
    UPDATE articles a SET a.position = a.position :operator 1
")->execute([
    'operator' => $operator
]);
```

In the SQL statement `UPDATE articles a SET a.position = a.position :operator 1`, the `:operator` parameters should be replace with `'+'`, from the previously defined `$operator` variable, but actually it running failes and returns this error:

> An exception occurred while executing 'UPDATE articles a SET a.position = a.position :operator + 1 with params ["+"]:
>
> SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''+' 1

Comment: if the `+` is somehow user-provided - never trust user input - check it thoroughly! I'm just assuming, so, if this is not a problem, just ignore it.;o)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not need to bind a literal character you have full control of.

And binding is for actual parameters. Reserved words, operators, database identifiers... all these are not "bound" into the SQL statement. Since these would never come from user input, it makes no sense doing so.

This could only be produced safely, from existing configuration, white-listed strings, etc.

Just interpolate the character in the connection string normally:

```
$operator = '+';
$conn = $entityManager->getConnection();
$stmt = $conn
    ->prepare("UPDATE articles a SET a.position = a.position $operator 1")
    ->execute();
```

Since you have no parameters, you could dispense with preparing the statement at all:

```
$stmt = $conn
    ->executeQuery("UPDATE articles a SET a.position = a.position $operator 1");
```